# ng-bind-html display unclosed tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to implement a search function on some text which highlights the characters which are being searched if they are present. However I've run into some odd cases where certain characters (`<`) are not being displayed.

In my template I have:

```
<span ng-bind-html="action.text | highlight: search.criteria.text:(!search.excludeScenesAndActions && search.active)"></span>
```

And here's my filter:

```
filters.filter('highlight', function () {
    return function (text, search, enabled, caseSensitive) {
        if (typeof (enabled) === 'undefined')
            enabled = true;

        if (enabled && text && (search || angular.isNumber(search))) {
            text = text.toString();
            search = search.toString();

            if (caseSensitive) {
                return text.split(search).join('<span class="search-match">' + search + '</span>');
            } else {
                return text.replace(new RegExp('(' + search + ')', 'gi'), '<span class="search-match">$&</span>');
            }
        } else {
            return text;
        }
      };
    }
);
```

The issue that I am having is with the `ng-bind-html` in the template, if my text is for example `<foo>bar <foo`, it will be displayed as `bar` because I am trying to render out the `<foo>` and `<foo` tags. I have tried to us `ng-bind` which works great however I want to actually render the `<span>` that is be

Answer (score 0):

Include `angular-sanitize.min.js` file in your `index.html` and add a app dependency where you are creating module that is `angular.module('appName', ['ngSanitize'])`. That's it, it will work fine. Just make sure that your returning value is to be correct